# WSO2 Organising APIS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-design, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 API Manager for exposing and securing our API's.
Its working fine.
Now we have actually a lot of API's in WSO2 API Manager. It looks like a long list of API's. Now its hard to find an API and do some changes. 
Is there any best practices for organizing them in API manager?May be group them based on functionality or url or anything like that.
Any inbuild support or suggestions?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such a support.

Comment: In publisher side you cannot group APIs. But in Store side you can group the APIs. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Customizing+the+API+Store

Comment: @Pubci please post your answer as an "answer" :)